# C - Get smallest possible signed integer

Tags: c, types, constants, signed-integer

Is there anything similar to Java's Integer.MIN_VALUE in C, which gives the smallest possible value of a signed integer, or do I just have to hard code the value myself?

Comment: Do not hard-code the value yourself; you will get the value wrong for some platforms that your code is moved to (because an `int` could have 16 bits, or 32 bits — by far the most common size — or 64 bits, or indeed other sizes).  But it is good that you asked before heading in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `limits.h` http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits

I think this is what you're looking for:
`INT_MIN = minimum value for an int`

Answer (score 5):

You will find `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` in `<limits.h>` (for plain int). Indeed, the header defines the limits for all the integer types: signed char, short, plain int, long and long long, with the prefixes `SCHAR_`, `SHORT_`, `INT_`, `LONG_` and `LLONG_`. All these are required to exist per ISO C99 and C11 (and, except for `long long`, in C89).

Answer (score 1):

In header [`limits.h`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/limits_h.htm)  you will get minimum and maximum value of data types.

For integer you can use -

```
  INT_MAX            //max value for signed integer

  INT_MIN           //min value for signed integer
```